# Custom error page on when application error occurred

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to show a custom error page when an application error occurred without changing the url?

When application error occurs, then how to show customer a custom error page without routing to another Url?

Comment: As you mention yourself - it's a custom error **page**, so it's a new page, a separate page - you cannot turn an existing page into an error page dynamically (or at least not easily) ..... what's the problem with redirecting to a separate, dedicated error page??

Answer (score 2):

Inside your web.config check that the configuration looks like:

```
<system.web>
  ...
   <customErrors mode="On">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/custom404.html"/>
   <customErrors
</system.web>
```

Comment: This works for only 404 errors, I want that how to redirect all appllication error redirect to ~/custom404.html?

Answer (score 1):

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/custom404.html">
</customErrors>
```

Comment: You should provide explanation for your answer, not only a code.

Comment: i know there are a lot of stupid rules around here for doing things the SO way, but some things are self-explanatory. take a holiday man.

Comment: Even if it is "self-explanatory", there is nothing said about file name and tag to which it should be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code too. For a MVC project one can ovverride the Controller's function OnException, perform some logging and other stuff then load the contents from an Error.URL in background where the error information is formated.

```
   protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext != null && filterContext.Exception != null && !filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            ViewBag.Exception = filterContext.Exception;

            filterContext.Result = View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            Log.Error(filterContext.Exception.Message +":"  + filterContext.Exception.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

In this snippet all Controllers in the project inherit from a BaseController where the function OnException is being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Web.config` file

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/errors/error">
</customErrors>
```

In any error it will redirect to the `/errors/error` page. Please note the `redirectMode` attribute. With the value `ResponseRewrite` the url will not change.

Now, if you want to show a different page for a specific error, you can set it with the following.

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/errors/error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/errors/error404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/errors/error500" />
</customErrors>
```